# Change Event in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Is there any event in the above mentioned namespace  to fire when any change occurs or when document edited ,for instance, text input occurs

I tried

**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_WindowSelectionChangeEventHandler** 
&
**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_EPostageInsertEventHandler**

But i can't trigger an event whenever i insert text in active word document.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Word object model does not expose any key press events,

List of Word events - [Document Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document_events%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You could try implementing a [global keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) to achieve what you're looking for through Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a rather old, but still very informative page on the MVPS Word site about using Word Events in VBA programming (http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm).
Please note the caveat at the end of the page that the use of some events may have a performance hit on Word; I remember also other pages expressing this caveat about "catch the type text event".

In fact, I'm developing Word solutions since 1994 and found rarely the necessity to catch the type event. I'd rather be afraid to mingle with the user input on this level, and would look for an alternative approach.